# Send LI value in another input value in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm in a React Project, where **after an axios.get, I get many LI inside an empty UL before the axios.get**.
When the LI are displayed after the axios.get, **I want on click on one LI, to send the LI value to an input value**.
I know how to do this with Jquery, (examples here: http://jsfiddle.net/Ender/QdWxH/ & http://jsfiddle.net/kbFUu/1/), but **I don't know how to do it in React**... Can someone help me ?

In my **src/App.js** I got the function

```
getValueFromLi = (evt) => {
  $('.App-Result-Li').on('click',function() {
    var content= $(this).text();
    $('.App-Form-Trips-cityDeparture').val(content);
  });
}
```

and in the **src/components/Results/index.js** (don't worry, I did well with the props, etc.), I got the callback

```
<li
   onClick={getValueFromLi}
   data-value={city.local_name}
   className="App-Result-Li"
 >
```

Do you know what is wrong in what I did ?

My project is on Github : **https://github.com/Versifiction/api-tictactrip**

Files involved : 
**src/App.js (https://github.com/Versifiction/api-tictactrip/blob/master/src/App.js)
& src/components/Results/index.js (https://github.com/Versifiction/api-tictactrip/blob/master/src/components/Results/index.js)**

Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could try like this:

```
<li
   onClick={() => this.provideLocalName(city.local_name)}
   data-value={city.local_name}
   className="App-Result-Li"
 >
```

also, you could parse the event object in your getValueFromLi function and do something with it then, e.g.

```
getValueFromLi = e => {
  console.log('li element: ', e.target)
  // do something with li, now you have reference to the dom node
}

<li
   onClick={this.getValueFromLi}
   data-value={city.local_name}
   className="App-Result-Li"
 >
```

Comment: hmm i don't even get the console log in the console, 
I think the <li onClick={getValueFromLi}> in the src/components/Results/index.js is not even reached..

Comment: try <li onClick={() => getValueFromLi()}>. It needs to be a function not yet executed

Comment: Oh my god, the problem was that I sended the function getValueFromLi as a prop but to another component, so the function never get to the Results component.... i'm so sorry, thank you for spend tiem to help me, I will like your answer, sorry !!!!!